# Magento2 reset password token not in readable code form

Tags: magento2, forgot-password

Magento2 how to convert resed password toke to readable format

In M2.3 do you now how was this rp token string getting converted to code that we enter
{{trans "your reset token :%token" token=$customer.rp_token}}

In 2.3 code was like 45678 & M2.4 it is string value 3djzQWgymtFYsc4sKNuCIDxUG3vVkcvm